# How to estimate confidence of nonlinear regression?

Tags: optimization, regression, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression

I use [Levenberg -- Marquardt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) to fit my nonlinear function `f(x,b)` (`x:Nx1, b:Mx1`) to data `X:NxK`.

Now I want to estimate goodness (confidence) of solution `b`.

[This post](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/why-is-there-no-r-squared-for-nonlinear-regression) says that I should not try to find R-squared in nonlinear case. What should I do then? Are there any reliable universal metrics at all? I could not google any answer for this.

Comment: The post that you mentioned has a suggestion at the bottom - Standard error of the regression.

Comment: @RandomGuy But what if `X` are such that some parameter `bi` affects `f(x,b)` very little at the solution `b`? Then S can be low, but `bi` will be estimated poorly.

Comment: @RandomGuy Consider this example: `f(x,b) = x1 * b1 + ...`. If `x1=0`, then `f(x,b)` can be made close to zero, but `b1` can't be estimated at all.

Answer (score 1):

Standard errors are usually calculated as:

```
s.e. = sigma^2 inv(J'J)
```

or as

```
s.e. = sigma^2 inv(H)
```

where

```
J : Jacobian matrix
H : Hessian matrix
sigma^2 = SSE/df = sum of squared errors / (n-p)
```

A confidence interval is then

```
b +- s.e. * t(n-p,alpha/2)
```

where t is the critical value for the Student’s t distribution